# list comprehension for pygal.Bar() x_labels

Tags: python, pygal

I am using pygal to simulate the dice rolling. I want to save it as `svg` file.

```
import pygal
from die import Die


die_1 = Die()
die_2 = Die(10)
results = []

for roll_num in range(50000):
    result = die_1.roll() + die_2.roll()
    results.append(result)

frequencies = []
max_result = die_1.num_sides + die_2.num_sides

for value in range(2,max_result+1):
    frequency = results.count(value)
    frequencies.append(frequency)

hist = pygal.Bar()

hist.title = "Result of rolling a D6 and D10 50000 times"
hist.x_labels = [x for x in list(range(2,max_result+1))]
hist.x_title = "Result"
hist.y_title = "Frequency of Result"

hist.add('D6+D10', frequencies)
hist.render_to_file('different_dice.svg')
```

But it gives an error:

> if len(string) > index and index > 0: TypeError: object of type 'int'
>   has no len()"

If I comment the list comprehension line

```
hist.x_labels = [x for x in list(range(2,max_result+1))]
```

it will work. Is there anything incorrect in this list comprehension?

Comment: Try outputting `max_result` and post what it outputs.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your kind reply. I just tried to make x to "str(x)" and it worked! So I guess the x_label of pygal.Bar() chart should be string, instead of the integer.

Comment: As the error shows `hist.x_labels` is not excepting an integer value, probably it should be a string, integer object don't have `len` or `__len__` function.

Answer (score 0):

In the string `hist.x_labels = [x for x in list(range(2,max_result+1))]` you don't use `list`, enough using only `range(2,max_result+1)`.

For example, in my program I used

```
histogram.x_labels = [num for num in range(2, max_result + 1)]
```